# Scala: executing external process, string escaping, and errors

Tags: scala, lynx

I want to execute the following command:

```
lynx -useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1' -source 'http://localhost'
```

as a `Process` in Scala. I used both:

```
val cmd = ... // command to execute
cmd #> new java.io.File( filename ) !
```

and:

```
val proc = Process( cmd )                                                  
proc !!
```

And in both cases I get errors from `lynx`:

```
Can't Access `file://localhost/home/me/Work/23.lynx/2.multidownload/(X11;'
Alert!: Unable to access document.
```

The command run alone works well, when I run it in Scala — I get errors. Which means that something strange happens between Scala and `lynx`, and the strings are not interpreted correctly… Any idea?

Comment: What is `cmd`? What is `filename`? What is `a`?

Comment: Sorry for that. `a` was an artifact from *vim*, and the code was cut-and paste, so I had those strange variables (edited)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am guessing you set `cmd` to a String. `!!` then splits up the string at each space character to get the arguments to pass to lynx, not caring about your `'` characters.

```
import scala.sys.process._

val cmd = Seq("lynx",
              "-useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'",
              "-source" "http://localhost")
val out = cmd.!!
```